# LinkedList RemovePosition Removing the Wrong Element

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm creating a Templated LinkedList and using it to simulate a train passing through stops. Each element of the `LinkedList` is an object of a `TrainCar` class with a `numberOfStops` variable. If this value is equal to 1 at a stop, the `LinkedList` is supposed to delete that element from the list. However, it ends up deleting the element before it instead.

I have tried modifiying both the `RemovePosition` function and the value I pass through this function and nothing seems to be solving the problem

Here is my `RemovePosition()` function in my `LinkedList` class

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::RemovePosition(int index) {
  if(index == 0) {
    RemoveFromFront();
  }

  else if(index == (size - 1)) {
    RemoveFromEnd();
  }
  else {
    node<T>* temp1 = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
      temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    node<T>* temp2 = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    size--;
  }
}
```

Here is my `main()` function code where the error is occurring

```
for(j = 1; j <= stops; j++) {
    cout << "Stop #" << j << ":" << endl;
    cout << "Train Arriving: ";

    for(i = 0; i < train.size; i++) {
      type = train.Retrieve(i).typeOfCar;
      id = train.Retrieve(i).finalID;
      numberOfStops = train.Retrieve(i).numberOfStops;
      cout << "[" << id << ":" << type << ":" << numberOfStops << "] ";
    }

    cout << endl << "Removing cars:" << endl;

    for(i = 0; i < train.size; i++) {
      numberOfStops = train.Retrieve(i).numberOfStops;
      if(numberOfStops == 1) {
        id = train.Retrieve(i).finalID;
        type = train.Retrieve(i).typeOfCar;
        cout << "[" << id << ":" << type << "] removed" << endl;
        if(train.Retrieve(i).typeOfCar == 'P') {
          addCargoCar--;
        }
        train.RemovePosition(i);
      }
    }
}
```

Here is my current output

```
Stop #1:
Train Arriving: [9:P:4] [5:P:2] [3:P:2] [10:C:2] [8:C:1] [1:C:2] [2:M:1] [4:M:5] [6:M:4] [7:M:1]
Removing cars:
[8:C] removed
[2:M] removed
[7:M] removed
Adding cars:
[11:P:2] added
[12:C:4] added
[13:P:4] added
[14:M:2] added
[15:M:2] added
Stop #2:
Train Arriving: [13:P:4] [11:P:2] [9:P:4] [5:P:2] [3:P:2] [12:C:4] [8:C:1] [2:M:1] [4:M:5] [7:M:1] [14:M:2] [15:M:2]
```

As you can see, the wrong `TrainCar`s were taken out. With these same inputs, the correct result for Train Arriving at Stop #2 would be:

```
Stop #1:
Train Arriving: [9:P:4] [5:P:2] [3:P:2] [10:C:2] [8:C:1] [1:C:2] [2:M:1] [4:M:5] [6:M:4] [7:M:1]
Removing cars:
[8:C] removed
[2:M] removed
[7:M] removed
Adding cars:
[11:P:2] added
[12:C:4] added
[13:P:4] added
[14:M:2] added
[15:M:2] added
Stop #2:
Train Arriving: [13:P:4] [11:P:2] [9:P:4] [5:P:2] [3:P:2] [12:C:4] [10:C:2] [1:C:2] [4:M:5] [6:M:4] [14:M:2] [15:M:2]
```

EDIT1: Implementing the solution provided by @leJohn, I now receive a segmentation fault. I believe this must be do to my call to the `RemoveFromEnd()` function as this solution works when I set my if condition to `if(numberOfStops == 2)` in my `main()` function. Here is my `RemoveFromEnd()` function

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::RemoveFromEnd() {
  node<T>* cur = head;
  node<T>* pre = cur;

  while(cur->next != NULL) {
    pre = cur;
    cur = cur->next;
  }

  pre->next = NULL;
  tail = pre;
  size--;
}
```

I don't see why this is causing an error...

Comment: Good opportunity to learn how to use your debugger to step through your code line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your loop :

```
for(int i = 0; i < index - 2; i++) {
      temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
```

by

```
for(int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
      temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
```

It should do the trick

Comment: Using this, I now get a segmentation fault. I believe it has to do with my call to the RemoveFromEnd() method as this loop works when I change my if condition to `if(numberOfStops == 2)`

Comment: I've updated my question to include my `RemoveFromEnd()` function. I don't see why this would be causing an error...

Comment: I guess your issues arrives because you delete elements of your list while iterating over it. This is generally a bad practice as you invalidate index and/or iterators. You should seek around this. Try a  i--  after removing an element